# 'lein jar' and 'lein uberjar' not setting the main-class properly

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

I ran `lein uberjar` on my project and it created the corresponding jar files. When I run the jar a `ClassNotFoundException: explodingdots.core` is thrown. I specified `explodingdot.core` as my main class. I extracted the jar file and there was indeed no `core.class` in the corresponding directory. What did I forget?

I have the following code in `src/explodingdots/core.clj`

```
(ns explodingdots.core  
 (:import (java.awt Color Dimension Graphics2D AlphaComposite RenderingHints)
          (java.awt.event ActionListener MouseAdapter WindowAdapter)
          (javax.swing Timer JPanel JFrame))
  (:gen-class))

[ ... ]

(defn -init[] exploding-dots)
(defn -main[_]
  (let [ed (new explodingdots.core)]
    (.init ed)))
```

The content of my `project.clj` is:

```
(defproject explodingdots "0.1"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]
  :main explodingdots.core)
```

**Note:** I am using leiningen 1.3.1

Comment: Try adding options :main true :prefix "-" to the gen-class form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: In fact, I fixed a problem that looks very similar to this one by *removing* `:main true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I solved my original problem. It is kind of embarassing to admit it, but I think I have to do it for the sake of completeness of this thread. I got mixed up with my paths. I have the same file within a Netbeans project and in a leiningen project. And I was editing the Netbeans file. Sorry.

But then I had an other problem. The main method is found but I get an

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core$-main
```

I tried changing my main method from 
`(defn -main [_] ...)` to `(defn -main [& args] ...)` like Arthur suggested but that didn't work. To solve this I wrote just `(defn -main[]...)` with no args.

The next problem was that calling `(init)` from `(main)` resulted in an error. I worked around that by not calling `(init)` at all but calling `(exploding-dots)` directly from `(main)`.

So to make everything work my `src/explodingdots/core.clj` looks like

```
(ns explodingdots.core  
 (:import (java.awt Color Dimension Graphics2D AlphaComposite RenderingHints)
          (java.awt.event ActionListener MouseAdapter WindowAdapter)
          (javax.swing Timer JPanel JFrame))
  (:gen-class))

[ ... ]

(defn -main[] (exploding-dots))
```

By looking at the solution I have to think, why didn't I write that right ahead. It is the most simple and most straight forward way. Maybe I need a vacation ;).

Comment: I also ran into the issue of needing a no-arg main method, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a third component to my main name space and move everything into the com subdirectory under src.

```
com.explodingdots.core
```

I also declare main to take an arg vector, not sure if that makes a diference:

```
(declare main) 
(defn -main [& args]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, and fixed it by adding

`:gen-class` to the corresponding missing class.